# WebGL Unable to compile a basic vertex shader

Tags: javascript, webgl, webgl2

I'm following Cherno's OpenGL course on YouTube,
I think I have a case of code blindness since I cant see anything wrong with my program.
Can someone help me out and tell me what I'm doing wrong or where the typo is..

I think the problem is the vertex shader or the way im linking it to the vertex attribute pointer, but im not sure; Any help would be great

The console outputs warnings:

```
WebGL warning: linkProgram: Must have a compiled vertex shader attached:
SHADER_INFO_LOG:
ERROR: 0:2: 'layout' : syntax error
WebGL warning: useProgram: Program must be linked successfully.
WebGL warning: drawArraysInstanced: The current program is not linked.
```

```js
function main() {
  const glCanvas = document.getElementById("glCanvas");
  const gl = glCanvas.getContext("webgl") || glCanvas.getContext("experimental-webgl")

  if (!gl) throw ("Your browser does not support WebGL");

  initWebGL();

  function initWebGL() {
    gl.clearColor(0.7, 0.7, 0.0, 1.0);
    gl.resize = function(width, height) {
      glCanvas.width = width;
      glCanvas.height = height;
      gl.viewport(0, 0, width, height);
    }

    const bufferData = new Float32Array([
      0.0,  0.5,  0.0,
     -0.5, -0.5,  0.0,
      0.5, -0.5,  0.0
    ])

    const buffer = gl.createBuffer();
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer);
    gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, bufferData, gl.STATIC_DRAW);

    gl.enableVertexAttribArray(0);
    gl.vertexAttribPointer(0, 3, gl.FLOAT, gl.FALSE, 3 * bufferData.BYTES_PER_ELEMENT, 0);

    const vertexShader = `
            layout(location = 0) in vec4 position;
            void main(){
                gl_Position = position;
            }
        `;

    const fragmentShader = `
            layout(location = 0) out vec4 color;
            void main(){
                color = vec4(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
            }
        `;

    const program = createShader(vertexShader, fragmentShader);
    gl.useProgram(program);

    gl.resize(500, 500)
    gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, 0, 3);

  }

  function createShader(vertexShader, fragmentShader) {
    const program = gl.createProgram();
    const _vertexShader = compileShader(gl.VERTEX_SHADER, vertexShader);
    const _fragmentShader = compileShader(gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER, fragmentShader);

    gl.attachShader(program, _vertexShader);
    gl.attachShader(program, _fragmentShader);
    gl.linkProgram(program);
    gl.validateProgram(program);
    gl.deleteShader(_vertexShader);
    gl.deleteShader(_fragmentShader);

    return program;
  }

  function compileShader(type, source) {
    const shader = gl.createShader(type);
    gl.shaderSource(shader, source);
    gl.compileShader(shader);

    return shader;
  }
}
```

```css
body {
    margin: 0px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body onload="main()">
  <canvas id="glCanvas"></canvas>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: It looks as if you would request a WebGL 1 context. WebGL 1 is using the OpenGL-ES 1.0 standard which does not support layout commands (and also doesn't support `in` for attributes). Also note that you have to specify a `#version` at the start of your shader code to request a specific glsl version.

Comment: minor correction: WebGL 1 is based on OpenGL ES 2.0 not 1.0 @BDL :)